# Handling post requests in HttpListener

Tags: c#, javascript, httplistener

```
private void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            _busy.WaitOne();
            try
            {
                HttpListenerContext context;
                try
                { context = _listener.EndGetContext(ar); }
                catch (HttpListenerException)
                { return; }

                if (_stop.WaitOne(0, false))
                    return;

                var sr = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream);
                string x = sr.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", context.Request.HttpMethod, x);
                //context.Response.SendChunked = true;
                using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(context.Response.OutputStream))
                {
                    //for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                    {
                        //tw.WriteLine("<p>{0} @ {1}</p>", i, DateTime.Now);
                        tw.WriteLine("<html><head></head><body>");
                        tw.WriteLine("Server Response");
                        tw.WriteLine("</body></html>");
                        tw.Flush(); //Catch http exception if client exists halfway through
                        //Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (_maxThreads == 1 + _busy.Release())
                    _idle.Set();
            }
        }
```

Above is my code, I can go to the URL with Chrome and few the reply even though the server shows it takes 2 get requests, I want to be able to handle POST requests, when I send a post request it reads it properly but the client doesn't get the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `ctx.Response.ContentLength64=...`. 
(you may also need `ctx.Response.Close()`)

Comment: When I use                         'byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
                        context.Response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;' I get a "bytes to be written to the stream exceed content length..." error

Comment: @Max0999 Also write your buffer to stream , not the original string (and you don't need TextWriter anymore.)

Comment: says "This stream does not support seek operations." when I use 'context.Response.ContentLength64 = tw.BaseStream.Length;' haha sorry for being a newb

Comment: just use `context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer,0,buffer.Length)`. `seek` is not needed.

Comment: I use '                Byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(responseString);
                context.Response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                context.Response.Close();' now but every response is still broken into multiple get requests.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is how the packets look `HTTP/1.1 200 OK..Content-Encoding: gzip..Vary: Accept-Encoding..Date: Thu, 18 Oct 2012 13:52:49 GMT..Server: LiteSpeed..Connection: close..X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10..Content-Type: text/html..Content-Length: 35`
and
`HTTP/1.1 200 OK..Content-Length: 63..Content-Type: text/html..Content-Encoding: gzip..Vary: Accept-Encoding..Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0..Date: Thu, 18 Oct 2012 14:17:13 GMT..Connection: close` the upper one is generated by a PHP server and works and the other one doesn't